# How to merge Word documets without changing the numbering

Tags: microsoft-word

I need to merge 50 Word docs into one Word file.
Each of the docs includes some numbering and multi-level numbering lists.

Is there a way to merge these docs and keep the original numbering defined in each doc ?
(I would like it to start at 1 each time and not continue from previous doc).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by numbering? Are these chapter numberings, page numberings, list numberings? etc...

Comment: I meant to list numbering. Each doc includes several lists with different numbering levels. I need that each list will start at 1 (or A or I - depends on its level).

Comment: I suspect you will have to do it the hard way: find the first item in each list and use the Set Numbering Value facility to restart the list post-merge. Or if you can use VBA, you may be able to find the beginning of each doucument post-merge (if there is something easy to find such as a paragraph with a Title style or some such). Or if necessary, put 49 such markers into a blank file, merge the documents in, then use VBA to look for the markers, find the first list item etc. Don't know whether that VBA would be simple or difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a section break will help. A [section break](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/insert-a-section-break-HA010031073.aspx) starts up new page numbers and so on and you can define different layouts for the pages.

BUT, if a heading type is used over different sections, there is a good chance the header numbers will not reset for each new section. Do you need to alter the document afterwards? Maybe you can just copy from the original and paste as text in the new document? You can [paste as text](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/control-the-formatting-when-you-paste-text-HA010215708.aspx) through the paste options.

Comment: A section break does not help. I did not use headings, and I need to keep the original format of each doc (so I can not use Past as Text)